# Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 'Failed resolution of: Landroidx/arch/core/executor/ArchTaskExecutor;'

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I was programming when I imported the newtonsoft, json library. Sudenly, when I execute my app shows this mesaje. It was never show before. [image]

I got back to the last succesful version of my project also I deleted the new library. But when I execute it, still the message. Also I tried to execute a new "hello world" Xamarin.Android app but it says the same. I can not deploy either the android emulator. It looks like all my Visual Studio crashed and my emulator too.

This is the error code:
[image]

What could I do? Desintall all the visual studio and intall it again? Is there a way to reintall only the Android Management Devices?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your Hello World, you will also need Xamarin.AndroidX.Arch.Core.Runtime  Version 2.1.0.8 if using Xamarin.AndroidX.App.Compat 1.2.0.7, so I suspect that you will also need it in your main project too. See https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidX/issues/278.

I'm using VS 16.10.0 Prev 1.0, so it may be different if using earlier versions of VS

Comment: Where I should add this package? Into the Android.Manifest.xml?

Comment: Adding the Xamarin.AndroidX.Arch.Core.Runtime NuGet solves it.